# How to change itemView in RecycleView after reading Firebase DB?

Tags: java, firebase, android-recyclerview

I have a list of Products and I'm using `recycleView` to show them.
I want to change the color of a few of them according to the data I have in a database.

I already have all the information and I just want to know how to do it right.
I just wrote a function inside the adapter class that reads from the database and gets all the products I want to color. I call this function in the constructor.

I don't know if I wrote it in the right place.

Anyway, my problem is that I want to read inside the - `onBindViewHolder` to `setTextColor`
But the data has not yet been updated so basically nothing is happening.

```java
 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProductItemView holder, int position)
 {
    holder.bind(mproductsList.get(position), barcodes.get(position));
    ....
    ....
    holder.nameProductTextView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
 }
```

`mproductsList` is the list of all products, some of which I want to paint in color.
Within the `.......` section I check if this product is in another container which I read from the database in the function I wrote above.

Comment: Maybe you can use `LiveData` or `RxJava` to implement reactive data populations with subscribe->observe pattern.

Comment: Do you want to change the color when something happens or when the data gets rendered?

Comment: @AlexeyUsharovski LiveData can be used when the underling data set changes. It seems like this is more of a conditional rendering

Comment: when data gets renderd.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using RecyclerView.Adapter since the method signature for onBindViewHolder only has two parameters. Firebase has its own adapter for recyclerviews, see [FirebaseRecyclerAdapter](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebaseui-android/database/readme.md/). It listens to the database for you so that you don't need to keep querying the database. Just implement the OnDataChanged method to do what you want to do when the data is updated.